# How to omit reporting files that have 100% coverage in Coverage.py

Tags: python, coverage.py

Is there a setting I can put in the `.coveragerc` file under `[report]` to omit files that have 100% test coverage in my report?

The closest thing I found was the `exclude_lines` option, but this only works for a regex pattern inside the code of your project, not for the report itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so. Try submitting a *Feature Request* or writing such a feature and submitting a *Pull Request*.

See: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html

Answer (score 2):

As of Coverage.py 4.3.2 is now a `--skip-covered` flag that can be passed to the `pytest coverage report` command.

Pytest can also be configured to skip files that have 100% coverage.

- https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.5.0/config.html#report-skip-covered